# Any idea why this regex doesn't work?

Tags: regex, apache

I'm using the code below in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)prod=\d+(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^dumbwaiters/proddetail\.php\?* https://www.example.com/dumbwaiters/compare-dumbwaiters/  [NC,R=301,L]
```

It redirects to:

https://www.example.com/dumbwaiters/compare-dumbwaiters/?prod=143

But I don't want the trailing ?/prod=143

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't the product ID kind of important? Do you not need it to access the correct product?

Comment: ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'l;kjhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhyfrtyuop[]\'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd

> When the requested URI contains a query string, and the target URI
> does not, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to copy that query
> string to the target URI. Using the [QSD] flag causes the query string
> to be discarded.
>
> This flag is available in version 2.4.0 and later.

So if your Apache version is sufficient, I think the below untested code would work:

```
RewriteRule ^dumbwaiters/proddetail\.php.*  https://www.example.com/dumbwaiters/compare-dumbwaiters/  [QSD,NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried with the additional . as noted above but it just went to the 404 page.